# Access_Callback problem

Tags: users

From time to time (and anytime after I run "drush cc all") my custom module with an access callback returns an 'access denied' error for Admins when they attempt to edit a user. I can solve this issue by disabling and re-enabling (any) module -- not just the one with the access callback code. If I remove this code, an admins ability to edit a user is fully and permanently restored. Here is the code in my custom module:

```
function cs_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['user/%/edit']['access callback'] = 'cs_user_edit_access';
}
function cs_user_edit_access() {
    global $user;
    if (!user_has_role(3, $user) || !user_has_role(4, $user)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this code would suddenly stop working, but I don't really want to lose the functionality that this custom code supplies (most of the time).

Comment: Is this in a module file or a .inc file? Also the argument should be `%user` which should be able to be passed to the function without doing global user.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you are checking the current users role. Is there a reason why you are not using permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve for my use case by dropping the secondary function, and just using the following code:

```
function cs_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access arguments'] = array('administer users');
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
}
```